# Including snippets of linked entities in ResourceSupports

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-hateoas

I'm trying to build a uniform REST facade that returns Spring HATEOAS `ResourceSupport` classes representing my domain resources, using `@ResponseBody` for JSON and Thymeleaf for HTML. I have a `Painting` class that looks like this:

```
public class PaintingResource extends ResourceSupport {
    private String title;
    private Integer year;
    // artist is a Link rel="artist"
}
```

For both the JSON and HTML rendering of `Painting`, I need to have a snippet of the artist's information available (e.g., name and URL for a profile picture), but it doesn't make sense to embed the entire `ArtistResource` class, and `Link` doesn't permit attaching any additional metadata.

Should I create a nested `Artist` class to hold just the snippet and create all of this in the resource assembler, or is there a more idiomatic way to mesh the snippet into `PaintingResource`? If I use a nested class, should I just embed the name and URL values and use a separate `Link` object to point to the artist's page?

Answer (score 1):

The [HAL proposal](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) ([draft spec here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-kelly-json-hal-05)) describes the solution that I think you're looking for - "embedded" resources within other resources, within the "reserved" `_embedded` property. Following this specification you can include full or partial snippets of other resources within another.

Spring HATEOAS supports HAL by adding the following to your configuration, I'm not sure of everything it does for you but it will output your `ResourceSupport`'s Links as a `_links` property.

```
@EnableHypermediaSupport(type = EnableHypermediaSupport.HypermediaType.HAL)
```

This doesn't seem to do anything specific for embedded resources (yet), but it's simple enough to implement with a property of

```
private Map<String, List<ResourceSummary>> _embedded;
```

in this case on your `PaintingResource` class. You'll probably want some kind of summary/snippet version of your `ArtistResource` to add here, but that will allow you to include it's own Links and set of properties that you wish to expose. So in your case

```
private Map<String, ArtistSummaryResource> _embedded;
```

Note that according to the proposal `_embedded` values can either be objects or a list of objects. We chose to always implement a list of objects for less complexity in the client.

I expect you'll end up with something like the following:

```
{
    "title": "Painting title",
    "year": 2014,
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://your.server.com/path/to/painting"
        }
    },
    "_embedded": {
        "artist": {
            "name": "J Smith",
            "_links": {
                "self": {
                    "href": "http://your.server.com/path/to/artist"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I read through the Spring HATEOAS HAL support a few minors ago, and at the time HAL looked like an XML-reminiscent potentially promising but potentially clumsy attempt at normalizing the semantics of link elements. I know the inclusion of URI templates has dramatically improved matters, and using the `_embedded` field looks like a reasonable approach (I was leaning toward a direct field inclusion of a snippet class, but this has a clean link-embedding solution).